# HTML safety fix for broken imported HTML content?

Tags: html

Im importing HTML into my page via an XML feed. If the content has an unclosed or unopened div (see below) it completely messes up the page.

```
<div>Stuff</div>
<div>Stuff</div>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div>
<div>Stuff</div>
<div>Stuff</div>
```

I know the best solution is to work on the PHP parsing, which im currently looking at. However as a backup or incase I cant find a PHP solution, is there an HTML fix?

I tried enclosing the entire imported area as a fieldset, ul and li, and span. I hoped this would effectively close any open divs, but none of them worked. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there an HTML fix?

No, there isn't. You need to fix the markup before adding it to the document.